# How can i see changes after a git fetch

Tags: git

Let’s suppose 2 users working on the same branch.

First user is changing a line in main.c file

Then, this user launch git add, git commit, and git push

Second user is changing the same line in the same file.
Then, this user does a git add and git commit.
Then, this user does a git fetch

This user does not launch git merge at this time. Second user wants first to check changes for main.c
Fetch opération is supposed to download main.c. But this is second user version which is visible. How can second user can see changes, before doing merge ?

If second user have to do a merge, he should do a pull instead. (Pull=fetch+merge)
So in which case we should do a fetch only ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that "same branch" is an illusion.

after doing `fetch` the history of user2 looks like this:

```
1 - 2 -> origin/the_branch
  \ 3 -> the_branch
```

So to see the difference made by the other user user2 should run:

`git diff the_branch origin/the_branch`